# How to access files outside /var/www/html

Tags: theme-customizer, apache

I'm using wordpress+apache2 and deploy it myself. I have created a custom mechanism to sync wordpress to git so that on the server itself I have to have symlinks between the synced wp-content folder and /var/www/html.
For example, on my server:

```
wp-content -> /temp/storefront-cms/wp-content
```

And in turn:

```
/temp/storefront-cms -> ff2cbcaf328b17f100f9446b1a49acf3b2e85b0c
```

It all worked well, but we need to change the theme now and the new theme seems to be using WP customizer in a way that makes the site crash. This is an example from the logs:

```
[21/Feb/2023:12:14:09 +0000] "GET /temp/ff2cbcaf328b17f100f9446b1a49acf3b2e85b0c/wp-content/plugins/kirki/kirki-packages/module-webfonts/src/assets/scripts/vendor-typekit/webfontloader.js?ver=3.0.28 HTTP/1.1" 404 114258 "https://mydomain/wp-admin/options-general.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

I'm not good at PHP, so not sure how to proceed. I tried to just enable /temp access in apache, but it didn't help and I'm still getting 404:

```
<Directory /temp>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I understand that it fails because GET request should go to `mydomain/wp-content...` instead of calling full path(`/temp...`), but I can't figure out the easiest way to fix it. Whether it should be on apache level or WP or both.

**UPDATE**

In general I don't understand why some WP components try to call other components by their full path. Even if I remove the symlink and just use /var/www/html, it doesn't seem right that the calls are made to https://domain/var/www/html/..... I don't think that server folder structure should be exposed directly. That's the whole point of having a server, like apache, after all.
What I see in network traffic:
[image: w]

Comment: symlinks aren't very reliable for this as you might find API functions return the original folder or file path not the symlinked version as you expect. This isn't something you can easily fix, and isn't officially supported by WP ( in the past issues have been raised related to this and the official response has been _no it's unsupported_ ). I strongly advise against using symlinks for this reason as it can cause crashes like the one you're experiencing. I'd also strongly avoid storing things top root level folders, especially temporary ones

Comment: Don't mind the temp folder name. I can call it anything else. It's not temporary. It's actually a persistent disk that's mounted at temp location. It will survive even if the node itself crashes.

Comment: Then again, I don't mind API funtions returning folder path. I then need a way to make that folder accessible. That's one of the options of how to fix it and I'm fine with it. The question is how to enable that access.

Comment: that may not have a WordPress based solution, PHP doesn't like symlinks and you should not rely on them, especially since those API functions are relied upon by WordPress itself. WP can and will receive incorrect folder paths with symlinks regardless of what theme or plugins you use. Is there a specific reason you aren't serving WP normally straight from the folder it's located in? Or mounting the folder directly into place instead of symlinking? The approach you've taken is a dead end

Comment: I don't know how to serve it directly from that folder. I'm using default path baked into a docker image. I can't mount folder directly into /var/www/html as I'm using git sync logic for bidirectional git synchorization of WP code, and that's how the sync works. I don't want to redesign it as it's a very stable and well knows open source tool.
I don't mind serving WP from the custom folder, but I need to research how to do that.
If you have good references, please share.

Comment: most docker based hosting systems mount the WP folder directly into the image at the location the image expects WP, use read only git folders for security reasons, don't serve `.git`, and also have a separate `wp-content` folder that is similarly mounted and usually comes from a separate git repo that the user administrates to. This is how a lot of enterprise WP hosts operate. Alternatively, they use these to assemble a WP install, archive that up, and deploy the archived result to a new server, destroying the previous one. constants in `wp-config.php` set the uploads/wp-content/WP folder

Comment: note that if you're using a well known open source tool you should share its name as that's enormously helpful, but you should also raise this with that tool as what you're doing is not how WP applications are normally configured, and while it may have worked well for you in the past, it isn't working for you right now and you've ran directly into a fundamental problem with this approach

Comment: Sure, I use https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync and to the best of my knowledge it fully depends on symlinks and you can't change that. It's actuall y quite smart as it uses commit SHA in the folder structure, which helped me a lot with debugging. At the same time, you don't want to use a path with commit SHA in it, so it allows you to have it symlinked to your folder of choice.

Comment: I don't use WP hosting system. I use infrastructure I manage separately.

Comment: Tom, if I redefine ABSPATH to point to a non-symlink location and make sure apache has access to it, should that work?

Comment: I don't have a lot of time to find another git tool and reconfigure CICD. But I can easily add some pre-start script that will update a var or a config file.

Comment: @TomJNowell, added an update to my question. In general, symlink regardless, why do some WP components try to make calls using server dir structure. Doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: it's not WP per say, it's a change in PHP from several years ago, WP simply chose not to build workarounds and support executing WP from a symlinked folder. As for ABSPATH etc, if you have an entry point and a config file, you can put WP on its own in a subfolder install, which is commonly done to facilitate using package managers like composer to install WP, as well as to mount read only copies of WP from other filesystems for security. As long as the folder is accessible from the browser you can serve it just fine

Comment: generally, WP itself is best served from a package or standalone location when used at scale, with user content aka `wp-content` being handled separately, ideally the two are not in the same repo. This is why managed WP's that use git repos that represent the root of `wp-content` with top level themes plugins etc folders

Comment: also, it is possible to mount 1 folder into another location on a linux system, without involving symlinks, but you'd need to ask how to do that on another stack as we're already moving far outside the realm of WP development

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143082/discussion-between-tom-j-nowell-and-yuranos).